# Where To Put Ad-hoc Commands/Queries in an Application That is Primarily DDD

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, procedural-programming, bounded-contexts

I am working on a web application using a domain driven design approach, however there are some aspects of my application that are not a good fit with DDD.  For example we need to do bulk updates of employee salaries. It is not efficient to load the entire employee entity and save it for each employee as there are often hundreds of salaries updated at once. Further, there are are other tasks that need to be performed at the same time such as logging the old salary and recording the effective date of the new salary. So I would say this type of operation is outside the bounded context of my core domain. Further I understand that this operation might best be approached from a procedural perspective. That's all fine and good, however I still want my application to be coherent and organized regardless of what approach I am using in a specific part of my app.

For example I am using the following structure.

- UI
- Application
- Model
- Infrastructure

I would like to stick to this structure even for things outside the bounded context of my core domain. My concern at the moment is primarily about my infrastructure layer. Originally I was using the following within Infrastructure:

- Repositories
- Finders (for separate read model)
- Commands

I put ad-hoc read queries in Finders and ad-hoc commands in Commands. The problem with this is that some operations require a series of queries AND commands and it seems more organized to me to group them all together in one unit. Kind of like a repository, but instead of providing access to domain entities it encapsulates a set of queries and commands that make up a specific procedure.

So what I am looking for is suggestions re naming conventions for changing the "Commands"  folder/namespace to something that better describes a series of queries/commands that logically fit together. Is there already a name/pattern for this that I am not aware of?

Update:

Am currently considering the namespace "Procedures" to describe the these queries/commands that logically fit together. On the one hand it is fitting because what I am describing is similar to stored procs and it is descriptive that this part of the application is using a procedural rather than DDD approach. My only misgiving is that this naming convention implies the use of stored procs, which is not the case.

Comment: I gave my repositories the ability to begin transactions, and then pass the TransactionCommand around to all repositories involved. Once the final repository is finished updating, I commit it. This way, I could still use my existing repositories (basically one for each model) without having to write ad-hoc / custom queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this [article first](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2013/12/16/Bulk-Actions-With-DDD-And-CQRS.aspx) it may help you with bulk updates. IMO Salary isn't a part of the Employee definition, I would say that either Salary is associated or needs an employee (as a reference ofc).

Changing the salary is a Domain use case and keeping the old salary seems to be a Domain rule. They do want to keep all the old salaries right? It's not a technical decision, but a business one. Personally I don't think it's the case for procedural mindset.

About having operations that require both queries and commands. Commands are something that change the Domain. You say those commands/queries make up a specific procedure. Of what? It seems you are describing a use case. Is it something known to the Domain? It requires business logic? Or is it **strictly** persistence or infrastructure related (update some read model, query other read model)? If there's logic it's a sign you might have a *service*. If it's business logic it might be a business concept, or a use case so they belong to the Domain. If its persistence logic it belongs to the DAL, if it's UI logic then it belongs to the UI etc.

**Update** *It was too long for a comment*

The point of the article was that if you need bulk stuff on Domain entities then in 99% of cases you're using the wrong model. In your case it does matter the relationship between an employee and salaries. I would say (just a very vague suggestion) that you can have a SalariesManager (bad name..) which would associate an employee (id) to a Salary starting from a specific date.

```
 public interface IManageSalaries
 {
      void ChangeEmployeeSalary(Guid employee, Salary newSalary,DateTime startingFrom);

     //possible bulk operation
      void ChangeSalary(Guid[] employees, Salary newSalary,DateTime startingFrom);          

      SalaryInfo[] GetSalaryHistory(Guid employeeId);
      Salary GetCurrentSalary(Guid employeeId);
 }
```

The implementation would just add a new (employee_id, salary, date) to a table. You change the current salary but also keep the old entries. The interface can be part of the Domain, but the implementation is part of Persistence (because it's simple and it doesn't contain business logic). Come to think of it, it does look like a repository, but without an aggregate root.

But this is *just a suggestion* . I get the feeling there is another solution that would fit better the Domain. It's up to you and the domain expert to identify it.

Comment: I read that same article before and I concluded from it that we should not use DDD for bulk updates and to go ahead and be CRUDy. It looks like you wrote the article so maybe I misinterpreted.

Comment: I understand that there needs to be a service and I did implement that, but that service calls into my data access layer which is in infrastructure. So all I was asking is how to organize the data layer to group together data access methods that belong together but incorporate both commands and queries. I eventually decided it does not matter if the are grouped together at the infrastructure layer. As long as the service groups together the related tasks, I decided it doesn't matter if they are separated at the infrastructure layer.

Comment: I think you are suggesting that I treat Salary as separate entity from employee and model Salary as part of the domain. It is a good suggestion. I will try that, but I do have cases that are more complex that seem to fit with a procedural style. Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228962/pending-updates-module-domain-entity-or-value-object) I asked where everyone pretty much agreed it was a case for using procedural code. I used salary in this case as my bulk update example because it was easier to explain.

Comment: Usually the procedural style is for simple cases. When you say complex cases (from the business point of view, not technical) it's a hint you need to do some Domain modelling. Btw, Salary isn't an Entity in this case, it's a value object. Why would someone need to id a salary. However, a RemunerationPackage which can include a Salary, Perks, Bonuses etc might be an entity because you would assign renumeration packages based on position, seniority etc so one  package is used for multiple employees and you may want to change the package as whole.

Comment: Have a look at the question I linked to. Sometimes things ARE too complex or to put another way, not a good fit for DDD.

Comment: I just realized you answered the question I referred to ... and in that case told me it was NOT part of the domain. So are you saying in the question I referred to I should use a procedural style, but not in the case of Salary?

Comment: You know DDD is for complex things. The more complex the better. In that question the code looked a lot like a technical solution not something belonging to the Domain. Does your Domain has the notion of Salary? It belongs to the Domain. Was PendingChanges a Domain concept? I doubt it.

Comment: OK, I get the distinction, though I do think that DDD "gurus" overstate things when they say procedural applies to simplistic things only. I would not consider the need track and apply changes effective on some future date as simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

Command/Queries in applications responsibility, look at the hexagonal architecture. You can add your ad-hoc command and queries as adapter/port to your application

Comment: I want all my persistence logic to be in one place, not scattered throughout the application. Also, in my case Commands/Queries are not application specific because there are multiple apps that must access this logic. ie web and console.

Comment: You can create web services for command/queries and others applications access to this services.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I already have that. What I wanted to know in my question was specifically a naming convention for the implementation of the persistence aspect of the commands/queries. ie In my infrastructure I have Repositories for domain persistence, Finders for read only queries. What do I call the third thing, ie logical groupings of commands/queries.

Answer (score 0):

I gave my repositories the ability to begin transactions, and then pass the TransactionCommand around to all repositories involved. Once the final repository is finished updating, I commit it. This way, I could still use my existing repositories (basically one for each model/entity) without having to write ad-hoc / custom queries.

I just wish I had my models/entities themselves Implement the repository interfaces, instead of defining a separate repository for each one. The former would allow for polymorphic repository operations, where the latter does not. Live and burn.

Here is a usage of a transactional repository, this method was taken from the Entity1Service class (my service layer, one class for each entity, contains static methods that use one or more repositories to complete some objective)

```
public class Entity1Service
{
    public static bool WriteEntity1(Entity1 entity1)
    {
        Entity1RepositorySQLite sqlRepo = new Entity1RepositorySQLite();

        sqlRepo.BeginTransaction(); 

        int entity1Id;

        if (!LocalIdService.ReadAndIncrementEntity1Id(out entity1Id, sqlRepo.TransactionCommand))
        {
            sqlRepo.RollbackTransaction();

            return false;
        }   

        int entity1IdOld = entity1.Id;  

        try
        {
            IdMapService.CreateMapEntity1Id(entity1Id, entity1Id, sqlRepo.TransactionCommand);

            entity1.Id = entity1Id;

            sqlRepo.Write(attachment);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sqlRepo.RollbackTransaction();

            attachment.Entity1Id = attachmentIdOld;     

            throw;
        }   

        sqlRepo.EndTransaction();

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Repository Definition**

```
public interface ITransaction
{
    SqliteCommand TransactionCommand { get; set; }
    bool InTransaction { get; }

    void BeginTransaction();
    void RollbackTransaction();
    void CloseTransaction();
    void EndTransaction();
}

public class RepositorySQLiteTransactional<T> : RepositorySQLite<T>, ITransaction where T : new()
{    
    public RepositorySQLiteTransactional(IDataMapperSQLite<T, string[]> dataMapper) : base(dataMapper) { }     

    public RepositorySQLiteTransactional(IDataMapperSQLite<T, string[]> dataMapper, SqliteCommand transactionCommand) : this(dataMapper)        
    {            
        _dbLayer.DblTransactionCommand = transactionCommand;
    }

    public SqliteCommand TransactionCommand
    {            
        get { return (SqliteCommand)_dbLayer.DblTransactionCommand; }
        set
        {
            _dbLayer.DblTransactionCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public bool InTransaction
    {
        get { return _dbLayer.DblInTransaction; }
    }       

    public void BeginTransaction()        
    {
        try
        {
            _dbLayer.DblBeginTransaction();
        }
        catch( Exception )           
        {
            _dbLayer.DblCloseTransaction();

            throw;
        }
    }

    public void RollbackTransaction()
    {
        _dbLayer.DblRollbackTransaction();
    }

    public void CloseTransaction()
    {
        _dbLayer.DblCloseTransaction();
    }

    public void EndTransaction()
    {
        _dbLayer.DblEndTransaction();         
    }
}    

public interface IRepository<T>
{        
    List<T> Read(IConditions conditions);     

    T FindOne(IQuery query);
    List<T> FindAll(IQuery query);

    void WriteOne(T obj);
    void WriteOne(T obj, out int newId);
    void WriteOne(IQuery query);
    void WriteAll(List<T> objs);

    void UpdateOne(T obj);
    void UpdateAll(List<T> objs);        
    void UpdateOne(IQuery query);

    void ReplaceAll(List<T> objs);

    void DeleteAll();
    void DeleteAll(List<T> objs);

    //void Add(T entity);
    //void Delete(T entity);
    //void Edit(T entity);
    //void Save();
}

public class RepositorySQLite<T> : IRepository<T> where T : new()
{
    protected AndroidDB _dbLayer;
    protected IDataMapperSQLite<T, string[]> _dataMapper;

    private RepositorySQLite()  // force data mapper init
    {

    }

    public RepositorySQLite(IDataMapperSQLite<T, string[]> dataMapper)
    {

    }

    public List<T> Read(IConditions conditions) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void WriteOne(T obj, out int newId) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    public void WriteOne(IQuery query) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

    private void ClearMapState()
    {

    }

    public void ReplaceAll(List<T> objs)
    {

    }

    public void WriteAll(List<T> objList)
    {

    }

    public void WriteOne(T obj)
    {

    }

    public void UpdateOne(T obj)
    {

    }

    public void UpdateAll(List<T> objs)
    {

    }

    public void UpdateOne(IQuery query)
    {

    }

    public T FindOne(IQuery query)
    {

    }

    public List<T> FindAll(IQuery query)
    {

    }

    public void DeleteAll(List<T> objs)
    {  

    }

    public void DeleteAll()
    {           

    }

    public void DeleteAll( IQuery query )
    {            

    }    
}
```